# Connection to internet terminates when I connect my Raspberry pi3(Model B+) to a VLAN which does not have internet connection

Tags: networking, wifi

I have a problem with my Raspberry pi. I have connected the PI to the wifi while setting it up for the first time and the internet access worked perfectly but when I connect it to a VLAN which does not have access to internet the connection to the internet is stopped. It seems that the PI automatically switches to the VLAN connection and then I cannot access the internet from the Pi. I need both the VLAN and wifi to work simultaneously as I need to push data to the cloud. Is it possible to have them working at the same time.

Thanks
Bipra

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static IP Issues For wlan0 and eth0](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98074/static-ip-issues-for-wlan0-and-eth0)

Comment: What is the meaning of "VLAN" in this context? Do you mean "LAN"? How is the LAN interface configured? Do you have a DHCP server that sets a default gateway?

Comment: "VLAN" sounds like a weird synonym for VPN, is that what you mean?

Comment: VLAN is a logical separation of different networks that share the same hardware. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN

Answer (score 0):

Your question provides insufficient information to provide a definitive answer, but **Prevent dhcpcd from configuring a gateway on an interface** in [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) describes a solution.